# Software for 3D scatter plot with 3D model for context

Tags: python, 3d, matlab, plotting

I'm searching for a software to plot scientific data into a 3D scatter plot PLUS I want to add a 3D model around to get context for the data.

[image: something like this maybe a bit more complex 3D models]

With Python and matplotlib Im doing fine with plotting the data but Im not able to add a 3D model into it. Also I got something like a "datacloud" witch describes the model I want to fit arround, maybe that helps. The shown image is done with MatLab but I have no idea how to do it. Googling for 3D Models in MatLab always leads to 3D wire plots and stuff. I was thinking about Blender maybe but some Python related thing would be my favorite.
Im a bloody rookie with coding but Im willing to learn.

greetings :)